# VB.NET: Getting each item in a ListBox and finding its text & index

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, listbox

I am attempting 2 separate ListBoxes for listing Offline and Online servers. The box refreshes every 3 seconds, and I need to be able to go through each item and get its text and index.

What can I do for this?

I've tried creating a For loop based on ListBox.Items but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you show with a little code what you have tried already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would probably want to use something along these lines:

```vb
For l_index As Integer = 0 To MyListBox.Items.Count - 1
    Dim l_text As String = CStr(MyListBox.Items(l_index))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this classic method:

```
     For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = i
        MsgBox("text: " & ListBox1.Text & "index: " & i)
    Next
```